# Как при наведении на элемент из группы элементов поменять CSS только его дочернего элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Всем привет! Решения на стаке для себя так и не нашел, поэтому спрошу сам :) Есть разметка:

```
<div class="top">
 <div class="buttons"><i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Кнопка 1</div>
 <div class="buttons"><i class="fa fa-etsy" aria-hidden="true"></i> Кнопка 2</div>
 <div class="buttons"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true"></i> Кнопка 3</div>
</div>
```

Задача в том чтобы при наведении на див "buttons" менялся цвет для его "i". Все мои попытки приводят к тому что меняются свойства элемента для всех 3х кнопок.

Comment: у вас в i ничего не заполено так и должно быть?

Comment: да это шрифт font-awesome

Answer (score 5):

Нужно воспользоваться селектором `>`, который выбирает непосредственного потомка.

Пример: `div > p`

В сочетании с наведением соответственно будет `.buttons:hover > i`

Больше о селекторах здесь: **[developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Селекторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B)**

Comment: Сработало замечательно, благодарю!

Comment: @Владимир если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте принять его (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```js
//Скрипт с применением hover из коментариев
$('.buttons').hover(function() { $(this).find('i').toggleClass('color'); });
```

```css
.color{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top">
 <div class="buttons"><i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true">test</i> Кнопка 1</div>
 <div class="buttons"><i class="fa fa-etsy" aria-hidden="true">test</i> Кнопка 2</div>
 <div class="buttons"><i class="fa fa-id-badge" aria-hidden="true">test</i> Кнопка 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Прекрасно! Благодарю!

Comment: В принципе, JS код можно сократить до `$('.buttons').hover(function() { $(this).find('i').toggleClass('color'); });`

Comment: @Regent, спасибо) с hover проблемы) мало опыта с ними. и даже не подумал что можно вприн и на css сделать)